# One that converses is a "conversOR" or "conversER"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns

If I want to nounify the verb *to converse*, meaning *one that involves in the act of conversation*, I naturally tend to say *speaker* or *talker*. What if I actually want to keep the stem of the verb?

Would it be *convers**er*** or *convers**or***?

Answer (score 1):

[Converser](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/converser) in American English.

Comment: I agree that this is the only possible spelling, but I would avoid this word. It appears in the dictionary, but I can't find any actual use of the word "in the wild"

Comment: I've used it in technical writing when a user role is defined this way, but never once anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

An option could be [**conversationalist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversationalist), though it carries the connotation of being good at or enjoying conversation, not just the bare fact of being involved in a conversation.

Ex:

> She's a really engaging conversationalist; she never runs out of interesting things to talk about.